# AQGridView background image

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

Can any one please tell how to set backgorund image for AQGridView. I checked but there is no setImage or any other keywords for it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer dudes its really simple

gridViewName.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image name"]];

The above code will give the background image for AQGridView. I should have thought that